# Regarding the system (shell) font on Surface Pro 4

Tags: windows-10, terminal, arch-linux, console, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I have set up my Surface Pro 4 to boot Arch Linux alongside Windows 10.  I don't use Plymouth or a DM, mostly because they were mostly more trouble than they were worth and it's just as well to start the window manager with startx anyway.

The trouble is, of course, that the SP4 is a very high-DPI device.  And while this is nice once I've got the window manager running, it is kind of challenging 
to use at startup.

[image]

You will notice that the console text is comically tiny and nearly impossible to read without a great deal of squinting.

What I wonder is: where is this font stored?  Upon (literally) close examination, it appears to be the same raster font that Windows terminals have used since the DOS days, but until now I never thought to wonder where it's actually generated.  And, of course, the inevitable follow-up is: can I change this anywhere?  It appears from the moment systemd-boot gives me a boot menu, and through the whole startup and shutdown process for Linux as well.  (I have never found a way to make it appear in Windows.)

I'd like to be able to modify this in some way to spare myself eye strain, but even if I can't then I am curious where this mysterious font is coming from.

Comment: [This Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Console_fonts) might be relevant. It also provides a list of usable fonts.